# In the PNP transistor, base current is the sum of emitter and collector current. How is this possible?

Tags: transistors, bjt, saturation

The PNP transistor at the right side doesn't follow any characteristics of the 4 modes of operation of BJT. How is this possible? PSPICE simulation has shown quite similar results. Here, beta=100.

[image]

[image: Picture of schematic]

Comment: The PNP seems to be in the saturation region. Why do you think that "*doesn't follow any characteristics of the 4 modes*" ?

Comment: Only the collector current value is Marked in the diagram. Please mark the emitter and base currents also. Current values marked at the resistor and the voltage source are **not** the emitter and base currents since there are junction points in between.

Comment: The PNP BJT is upside down - the collector and emitter are swapped.

Comment: I have added a picture of the schematic. As it can be seen in the PNP, the emitter current(3.289mA) and collector current(4.552mA)  are flowing in the base and their sum is 7.840mA. The base current is flowing out of the PNP, that's why there's a negative sign.

Comment: I have added a GIF file, the flow of current is indicated there. Hope it helps.

Comment: Replace the PNP with a two diode equivalent circuit and you will see why the current is flowing this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that the PNP transistor base terminal is at \$0V\$ (GND).
The collector is pull-up via \$R_2\$ resistor to \$+10V\$. The emitter is also at a higher potential than the base terminal.

So the situation looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX2T1N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>